# Allocated Message crash in google protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a crash using protobuf, i need to use it with reflection.

```
enum ipVersionType{
    ipv4 = 0; 
    ipv6 = 1;
}

message IpAddress {
  required ipVersionType ipVersion = 1;
  required uint32 IpPart1 = 2;
  required uint32 IpPart2 = 3;
  required uint32 IpPart3 = 4;
  required uint32 IpPart4 = 5;
}
message TcpUdpCdr {
  ...
  optional IpAddress    DestinationIp = 8;
  optional IpAddress    UEIP = 11;
  optional uint32   PacketUpLink = 12;
  ....
}
message cdr {
  optional TcpUdpCdr tcpCdr = 1;
}
```

When i use TcpUdpCdr without cdr, i got no crash.

If I use TcpUdpCdr within cdr, i got a crash.

here is the code that i am using to set Ipaddress

```
//Fill proto ip address sruct 
ProtoCdr::IpAddress * ipAddressMsg = new ProtoCdr::IpAddress();
ipAddressMsg->set_ipversion(ProtoCdr::ipVersionType::ipv4);
ipAddressMsg->set_ippart1(pi_ipAddress.GetAddresPointer()[0]);
ipAddressMsg->set_ippart2(pi_ipAddress.GetAddresPointer()[1]);
ipAddressMsg->set_ippart3(pi_ipAddress.GetAddresPointer()[2]);
ipAddressMsg->set_ippart4(pi_ipAddress.GetAddresPointer()[3]);

google::protobuf::Message& find_msg = cdrMsg.GetReflection()->GetMessage... with local recursive function
find_msg is of type TcpUdpCdr
find_msg.GetReflection()->SetAllocatedMessage(
    &find_msg,
    ipAddressMsg,
    this->m_fdArray[m_iNestingSize-1]);
```

Up to here ther is no crash...

If i try to get the pointer with GetReflection GetMessage, i receive the same pointer address that have been Set with SetAllocatedMessage but when i try to use it it crash. It crash for the second IpAddress UEIP but not for the first one....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `SetAllocatedMessage` to assign ownership of `ipAddressMsg` to `find_msg`, but `ipAddressMsg` is already owned by `cdrMsg`. Because `ipAddressMsg` is now owned by two different protos, you will quickly run into problems because both owners will eventually try to delete it. I think your code is trying to use that submessage after it has already been deleted.

Note that in general with protobuf, methods that contain the word `release` or `allocated` are a bit of an advanced feature--they can improve performance but they increase complexity and require you to do more manual memory management. With those methods it's easy to accidentally run into memory leaks, double deletes, and use-after-delete. Unless you really need the performance, it's best to avoid them. In your case, you could just assign to the result `MutableMessage()` instead of calling `SetAllocatedMessage()`.

Comment: I didn't understand why you said "ipAddressMsg is already owned by cdrMsg". There are 2 IpaddressMsg under TcpUdpCdr, not under cdrMsg each one is filled by SetAllocatedMessage with the distinct fieldDescriptor.  I Understood that SetAllocatedMessage will take care of memory, Performance is important to me. And I look at memory with protobuf GetMessage which will return the correct memory to use.

Comment: And also each SetAllocatedMessage is called with a distinct allocation of ProtoCdr::IpAddress *.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your code. It does look like ipAddressMsg is a new allocation not owned by another proto. Still, without seeing the full code I would be suspicious of the SetAllocatedMessage call--I would suggest getting the code working without any using any of the `allocated` and `release` methods and then optimize afterward. It might also help to run the code under Valgrind or ASAN.